# How do you read the contents of &mut [0; 128]?

Tags: tcp, rust

I've been reading through [the Rust documentation](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/) and made it to section 4.26 before looking at the libraries included. [`std::net::TcpStream`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/net/struct.TcpStream.html) caught my eye but I don't understand the following lines:

```
let _ = stream.write(&[1]);
let _ = stream.read(&mut [0; 128]);
```

I have seen `[0; 128]` before under [Vectors](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/vectors.html) as `vec![0;10] // Ten 0s` so I can see that a buffer of 128 `0`s is passed in. The documentation for `read` says "Pull some bytes from this source into the specified buffer, returning how many bytes were read." so how can you access the data that was read into the buffer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The comment in the code indicates that the result is ignored:

```
let _ = stream.read(&mut [0; 128]); // ignore here too
```

To get the data, you need to create a variable:

```
let mut buffer = [0; 128];
let _ = stream.read(&mut buffer);
// The data is in buffer.
```

Comment: Oh, I thought that it was being ignored with `let _ =`. I now see that both the return value and the sideeffect were being ignored.